# Word for "ashamed smile."

Tags: single-word-requests

By "ashamed smile" I mean something like this:

[image]

I thought of the word *sheepish*, but I think it's more related to guilt? What I'm looking for is something that has more to do with shame, like when someone recognizes you but calls your nickname instead of your actual name.

Comment: I would say *sheepish* is just fine, since it connotes embarrassment but not necessarily guilt. The word to stay away from if you don't want the guilt connotation would be *shamefaced*.

Comment: I'd decribe that person's smile in the photo as being "forced", "fake", "strained", or even "stretched", pretty much anything but *embarrassed* or *wan* = a sickly type of smile

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **ABASHED** *verb* past tense: abashed; past participle: abashed
>
> cause to feel embarrassed, disconcerted, or ashamed.
>   "she was not *abashed* at being caught"
>
> ***synonyms***: embarrassed, ashamed, shamefaced, remorseful, conscience-stricken, mortified, humiliated, humbled, , crestfallen, sheepish

from [**Merriam-Webster Dictionary**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=abashed+definition&gws_rd=ssl)

Answer (score 2):

A [shamefaced](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/shamefaced) smile may fit in your context:

> - feeling or showing shame: shamefaced apologies.

- There was a trace of another pattern of behaviour in that shamefaced smile.
- Not that I've ever seen a sheep smile, but there it was — a soggy, sorry, shamefaced smile.

Answer (score 1):

In the book *How to Read a Person Like a Book* by Gerard I. Nierenberg and Henry H. Calero, such a smile is named after its shape, *oblong*, which [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/oblong) defines as:

> Having the shape of or resembling a rectangle or ellipse.

An excerpt from [Nierenberg and Calero](https://books.google.com/books?id=4tK3BMnGNCsC&pg=PA22&dq=oblong+smile&hl=en&sa=X&ei=nGrWVPCGCoWoyATbk4HYCw&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=oblong%20smile&f=false) describes it thus:

> Smiles should not always be associated strictly with happy moments. "Beware of the oblong smile," says Dr. Ewan Grant of Birmingham University. He uses this name for the smile that many of us tend to use when we have to be polite. **The lips are drawn fully back from both upper and lower teeth, forming the oblong with the lips** [emphasis added]. Somehow there is no depth to this smile. "This is the smile or grimace when one is pretending to enjoy a joke or off-the-cuff remark. Or when a girl gets too much attention from a drunk, or is being chased around the office by the boss."